# How should I report "combined hazard ratios" for time-varying covariates in Kaplan Meier survival analysis

Tags: survival-analysis

Thanks for reading. I am working with a Cox proportional hazards model to do a survival analysis.

I have an exposure variable which violated the proportional hazards model assumptions and therefore needed to be split into two time frames: Time before split (T1) and time after split (T2).

Along with the time splits, I'd like to report the combined hazard ratios in a plot, but I'm not sure if i am doing this correctly. Let's say T1 HR = 1.34 and T2 HR = 1.15. i seem to recall i could multiply both together to get an overall measure, so 1.34 * 1.15 = 1.54.

Is this the correct approach or am i missing something obvious?

Thank you all for any insight.